# Collection data from different API and sending them all together in a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I want to retrieve product from multiple pages of the API

like

```
https://example.com/v2/nodes/?resource__type=device&page=1 
https://example.com/v2/nodes/?resource__type=device&page=2
.
.
```

Each page have the link for next API like this:
 var devices = JSON.parse(body);
devices.links.next

I want to retrieve all the data from all page. And I also want to call another function when all data is called.

my Code:

```
getAllNodeData(1,"https://example/v2/nodes/?resource__type=device&page=", 'A').then(function(objectList){

    console.log('--------')
    console.log(allProducts.length)
})

function getAllNodeData(currentPage,url,key){

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var result
    httprequest(url+currentPage,
        function(err, res, body) {
            var devices = JSON.parse(body);
            var next;
            var tempDeviceObject = {}
            //console.log(devices)
            saveProducts(devices.objects,key)
            if(devices.links.next != null){
                currentPage++
                return getAllNodeData(currentPage,url,key)
            }else{
                console.log('I am here')
                result =  deferred.resolve(allProducts);
            }
           // if(devices.totalObjects == allProducts.length){

            //}

        })

    return deferred.promise;
}



function saveProducts(objects,key){
    if(key === 'A'){

        objects.forEach(function (device) {
            var tempDeviceObject = {}
            tempDeviceObject.id = device.uid
            tempDeviceObject.name = device.label
            tempDeviceObject.type = device.resource.slug
            device.publishes.forEach(function(pub){
                if((pub.label=== 'Motion') && (pub.type.toLowerCase() === 'motion')){
                    var currentPage = 1;
                    var key = 'M';
                    var url = "https://crossoft:snSprynet0@apis.sen.se/v2/feeds/"+pub.uid+"/events/?page=";
                    tempDeviceObject.motion =pub.uid
                 //  return  getEventsOfPublishes(pub.uid,url,key,currentPage)
                }else if((pub.label=== 'Battery') && (pub.type.toLowerCase() === 'battery')){
                    tempDeviceObject.battery =pub.uid
                }else if((pub.label=== 'Temperature') && (pub.type.toLowerCase() === 'temperature')){
                    tempDeviceObject.temperature =pub.uid
                }
            })

            allProducts.push(tempDeviceObject)

        })
        return allProducts
        //console.log(allProducts.length)
    }
}
```

In the above done I want to return allProducts when devices.links.next != null is true i.e next = null. Currently .then function is not working . I am using q module.

Thanks for Your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Where is `allProducts` initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its one change required only.

```
return getAllNodeData(currentPage,url,key)
```

replace above line in getAllNodes with following one, and all will go okay

```
getAllNodeData(currentPage,url,key).then(function(){
 deferred.resolve(allProducts)
});
```

Happy Helping!

Comment: you can keep also make use of return getAllNodeData if you wrap httprequest to return promise, it will make code easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, you [really should](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) do that. @Zeeshan can you please show how?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the line

> ```
> return getAllNodeData(currentPage,url,key)
> ```

in the nodeback. You cannot `return` from there, returning only works in `then` callbacks.

Also, you are using the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572). Instead, [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) only the `httprequest` function, and from then on use only promises. In your case, the function should look like this:

```
var promiseRequest = Q.nfbind(httprequest);

function getAllNodeData(currentPage, url, key) {
    return getNodeData(currentPage, []);

    function getNodeData(currentPage, allProducts) {
        return promiseRequest(url+currentPage).then(function(res, body) {
            var devices = JSON.parse(body);
            var tempDeviceObject = {}
            allProducts = saveProducts(devices.objects, allProducts)
            if (devices.links.next != null) {
                return getNodeData(currentPage+1, allProducts)
            } else {
                console.log('I am here')
                return allProducts;
            }
        });
    }
    function saveProducts(objects, allProducts) {
        if (key === 'A') {
            objects.forEach(function (device) {
                var tempDeviceObject = {
                    id: device.uid,
                    name: device.label,
                    type: device.resource.slug
                };
                device.publishes.forEach(function(pub) {
                    if ((pub.label==='Motion') && (pub.type.toLowerCase()==='motion')) {
                        tempDeviceObject.motion = pub.uid;
                    } else if ((pub.label==='Battery') && (pub.type.toLowerCase()==='battery')) {
                        tempDeviceObject.battery = pub.uid;
                    } else if ((pub.label==='Temperature') && (pub.type.toLowerCase()==='temperature')) {
                        tempDeviceObject.temperature = pub.uid;
                    }
                });
                allProducts.push(tempDeviceObject);
           });
        }
        return allProducts;
    }
}
```